# 404 errors and "repository does not have a release file" when using 'sudo apt update'

Tags: apt

When running the command `sudo apt update` I get the following problems that bothers me a lot:

```
$ sudo apt update

Hit:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu eoan InRelease    
Hit:2 https://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease               
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:4 https://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:5 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease       
Ign:6 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/88 buster InRelease
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Hit:8 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/88 buster Release
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

When trying to use `sudo apt autoremove` I get the following result:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

Comment: I concur with HappyTux regarding the state of the sources list. As for the dpkg lock, could you update your question to include the output of `ps aux | grep -i apt`? The solution may be just a couple of clicks.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're using Ubuntu?

Comment: What's the OS? Hirsuite is in beta (so we don't fully support it here). Mixing repositories from different distros and even versions causes issues like this. I suggest you [edit] and post the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and output of `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: I'm using chrome os. Which has ubuntu in only one window if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: For me, I was getting that error because I was using an unsupported Ubuntu version at that moment. ubuntu 22 worked but Ubuntu 23 did not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove all the useless repositories you have in it. You have lines for two different and incompatible Ubuntu releases, Debian buster which is incompatible with both of those and the third party repositories who knows if compatible, I am not going to check. The file is a mess and will never produce a stable system. The third party sources can be in  your `/etc/apt/sources.d/` directory the location for them third party installed sources. Comment out the lines in those files by putting a `#` at the start of the lines that do not have one or removing the file completely, then `apt update` to have it re-read and update the package cache.

Comment: When opening sources.list, I have only the files:
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main

Comment: Then they are in your `/etc/apt/sources.d/` directory the location for third party installed sources. Comment out the lines in those files by putting a `#` at the start of the lines that do not have one or removing the file completely, the `apt update`. You want at least the `Ubuntu` removed as it appears you are supposed to be running `Buster` from that response. I have edited the response to reflect the third party location.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to remove the files that were causing the problem, they were exactly in /etc/apt/sources.list.d. Everything is going normally now.

Comment: Good to read it is solved, in the future only put in lines that are confirmed to be compatible with `Buster`, this will allow the software to be used with your system.

Comment: What do you mean by "useless repositories"? Which ones are useless? How can we tell that they are useless?